# using a combination of positional parameters and 1 named parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, getopts

I am still "baking"  my  shell with these features so my question may not sound like "totally ready" ..its more of a "whats the best way to design this"  as against something like "I ran into this error or this wont work..now what do I do ", so bear with me pl. while I explain 
I am thinking of a shell program which can be run in 2 modes

- Standard Mode is a bunch of  positional parameters 
  e.g. `myprogram date1 date2 date3 date4  # can go on indefinitely`
- Named Parameter mode 
   `myprogram -r date1 # Just 1 date para allowed`

They are of course mutually exclusive `myprogram date1 date2 date3 date4` is ok 
 
`myprogram -r date1 date2 date3 date4` is not because 1 only parameter is expected with `-r`

I am aware of `getopts`  offering a named parameter feature that can `shift` through a bunch of options. 

I have the standard mode ready & working  and would like to "add" to the code to get the named parameter mode 
In standard mode my code is  patterned like

```
for args
do
stuff that I want done here 
shift
done
```

So here is what I am thinking for the named parameter mode logic 
(When I use getopts and more that 1 positional parameters is used It should quit. )

 With getopts allowing  just 1 parameter, I am thinking of some like this

```
while getopts "r:"  opt; 
do
case statement of getopts 
<stuff I want to do >
esac 
done
```

and for limiting positional paras to just 1 I should have something like this ? 
`[ "$#" -eq 2 ]  ||  die " more than 1 para not expected here"`
the 2 is because while i am in the while loop above , `-r` is the 1st pos. para and 1 para is the variable one that gets in there. I have to do the checking within the loop because  , I want it to fall through  without anything being done if `-r` option is not used , in which case I can have as many pos parameters as I need 

So how do I cook this best- is what I am trying to understand.
Put the `getopts` code 1st and then follow through with  the  positional parameter code ? 
Sorry if I could be too specific in my question.

Comment: Is there a difference between `myprogram date1` and `myprogram -r date1`? If not, don't clutter your interface with unnecessary options.

Comment: Yes there is  `myprogram date1` gets  just the 1st level dates and `myprogram -r date` will get  the data recursively and that is why the recursive option needs just 1 date parameter not a bunch of em. Thanks for looking  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't always use getopts, but when I do, it looks something like this:

```
...

#Defaults
Verbose=false
ropt=false

# Options
while getopts vr: opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    v)  Verbose=true; vopt="-v" ;;
    r)  ropt=true; rarg="$OPTARG" ;;
    *)  usage; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if $ropt && [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  $Verbose && echo "Too many arguments. Bye." >&2
  exit 1
elif $ropt; then
  args=( "$rarg" )
else
  args=( "$@" )
fi

# then...
for thing in "$args"; do
  ... something with $thing ...
done
```

The first condition after the getopts loop controls whether you're running in multi-argument or single argument (`-r`) mode. The subsequent `else`s populate the `$args` array, which you can then do whatever you like with later.

Answer (score 1):

I use `getopts` instead of `getopt` but I assume logic is the same. Loop through the named options and then once you're done, if you haven't set your option, just use the remaining options.

```
ARGS=$(getopt --options=r: --name="$0" -- "$@");
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo_usage
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$ARGS";

while true; do
    case $1 in
        -r)
            shift
            date1=$1
        ;;
done

if [ -z "$date1" -a ! -z "$1" ]; then
    date1=$1
fi
```